# how to print block of lines matching a pattern using awk?

Tags: awk, filtering

I have a text file like list:

```
-----> 2012-02-13 19:29:27.325 <http-0.0.0.0-9090-1> at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.executeQuery(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:236) 
  at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:187) 
  at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1787)
  .... (many lines starts with at)

5. select * from mytable

-----> 2012-02-13 19:31:27.325 <http-0.0.0.0-9090-1> at 
... (many lines start with at, just like above)
```

I want to print the block of lines starting with `-----> 2012-02-13` if the line starting with `5. select` contains the keyword `mytable`.

How to do that with awk?

Comment: But if you start a new block with 2012-02-13, or if the line starting with '5. select' does not contain 'mytable', then ignore the material?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
awk 'BEGIN {RS="----->"} /5\. select \* from mytable/ { printf("%s %s",RS,$0)}' INPUT_FILE
```

If I had understood correctly what you need (print the block, if `5. select * from mytable` is in there). If you want a reversed output, try:

```
awk 'BEGIN {RS="----->"} ! /5\. select \* from mytable/ { printf("%s %s",RS,$0)}' INPUT_FILE
```

[See it in action here](http://ideone.com/B8dpz).